# Given any sequence of real numbers $a_n$, show that there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ of $a_n$....

Tags: real-analysis

Given any sequence of real numbers $a_n$, show that there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ of $a_n$ and a real number $b$ such that $\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\mid b-\dfrac{a_{n_k}}{1+\mid a_{n_k}\mid}\mid$ is convergent.

I tried like this. For any subsequence  $a_{n_k}$ of $a_n$ , the sequence $\dfrac{a_{n_k}}{1+\mid a_{n_k}\mid}$ is always a bounded sequence. Hence it contains a convergent subsequence. Now from this I got stuck. please help

Comment: Let $b$ be the limit. Then pass to a further subsequence to get the sum to converge.

Comment: As you said, the sequence is bounded so we can extract a subsequence which I denote $(b_n)$ for convenience that converges to some $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, consider the sequence $|\ell-b_n|$, which converges to 0. We want to make sure that it converges quickly enough, so we extract a subsequence $(c_n)$ such that at each step $0\leq c_n\leq 2^{-n}$.

Comment: A subsequence of a subsequence is a subsequence (of the original sequence). However, why not state that $\frac{a_n}{1+|a_n|}$ is bounded in the first place - and look for a convergent subsequence of *that*?

Comment: @charlus , i think your claim is not correct. For example consider the sequence $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$. I think it will not satisfy your inequality

Comment: @J.Doe: With $a_n=1/n$, define $k_n= 2^n$ and then $c_n= a_{k_n}$. The sequence $(c_n)$ verifies the desired inequality.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

let $a_{n} > 0$ then $a_{n}+1 > 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{a_{n}+1}<1$

$\dfrac{a_{n}}{1+\mid a_{n}\mid}=\dfrac{a_{n}}{1+a_{n}}=1-\dfrac{1}{1+a_{n}}<1$  which means it is bounded so there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}$

$a_{n_k}$ is convergent $\Rightarrow$ $\dfrac{a_{n}}{1+\mid a_{n}\mid}$ is convergent

$\dfrac{a_{n}}{1+\mid a_{n}\mid}$ is convergent  $\Rightarrow$  $\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\mid b-\dfrac{a_{n_k}}{1+\mid a_{n_k}\mid}\mid$ is convergent

let $a_{n} < 0$ then $1-a_{n}>1$ $\Rightarrow$ $-1<\frac{1}{1-a_{n}}<0$

$\dfrac{a_{n}}{1+\mid a_{n}\mid}=\dfrac{a_{n}}{1-a_{n}}=\dfrac{1}{1-a_{n}}-1>-1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mid \dfrac{a_{n}}{1+\mid a_{n}\mid}\mid <1$ which means it has a convergent subsequence $a_{n_k}$

$a_{n_k}$ is convergent $\Rightarrow$ $\mid \dfrac{a_{n}}{1+\mid a_{n}\mid} \mid$ is convergent

$\mid \dfrac{a_{n}}{1+\mid a_{n}\mid} \mid$ is convergent $\Rightarrow$ $\sum\limits_{k\geq1}\mid b-\dfrac{a_{n_k}}{1+\mid a_{n_k}\mid}\mid$ is convergent

NOTE: I also found  an article that may help you [If $(a_n)$ is any real sequence , then $(\frac{a_n}{1+|a_n|})$ has a convergent subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308610/if-a-n-is-any-real-sequence-then-fraca-n1a-n-has-a-convergent?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a $b$ and $(n_k)|_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that
$\dfrac{a_{n_k}}{1+\mid a_{n_k}\mid}
\to b
$,
we can choose a subsequence
$(n_{k_m})|_{m=1}^{\infty}$ of $n_k$
such that
$\left|\dfrac{a_{n_{k_m}}}{1+\mid a_{n_{k_m}}\mid}- b\right|
\lt \dfrac1{2^m}
$,
and the sum of these converges.